# LibreOffice Calc Error 518

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to achieve the following in LibreOffice (did it with Excel already, but importing this excel-created file produces the same error).
I have 3 columns

```
    (A)  (B)  (C)
    ECTS Mark Done-ECTS
    3    4    3
    3         Err 518
    2    2    2
```

So I want to calculate how much ECTS I have achieved so far.
The Formula for the Done-ECTS Column is the following:
=IF(ISBLANK(B2) , ,A2);
So IF the Mark is empty (not done yet), show nothing. If I already have a mark, display the ECTS.
I can't insert something like "" because I make a sum of my Done-ECTS, and "" resolves in an #Value error.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the test, use:

> =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),A2)

or

> =IF(ISNUMBER(B2),A2)

or

> =IF(ISBLANK(B2),0,A2)

Comment: well that way I'm not getting the Error 518, but it only says TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: @sk1ll My version of LibreOffice (4.3.5.2) allows `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",A2)` and the SUM function takes it as zero. I suppose that you could always use `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),0,A2)`.

Comment: oh I'm sorry I took a comma too much I think, now I'm getting a 0. Thank you! 
However with your second comment the scales fell from my eyes... I always thought the cell needed to be _empty_ , but a 0 totally does the trick..